# Bash script, replace text in file?

Tags: bash, ssh

I currently have

```
echo -n "MySQL Database Name:  "; read MyVar; sed -i 's/database_name_here/$MyVar/g' config.php
```

It partially works, it prompts me to enter a database name. Once entered it updates the file but it's still putting $MyVar instead of what's typed.

```
echo -n "MySQL Database Name:  "; read MyVar; echo "$Myvar"
```

^ works just fine.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
echo -n MySQL Database Name: ; read MyVar; sed -i s/database_name_here/$MyVar/g config.php
# ////
echo -n MySQL Username: ; read usr; sed -i s/username_here/$usr/g config.php
# ////
echo -n MySQL Password: ; read blackberg; sed -i s/password_here/$blackberg/g config.php
```

If it's just one line on the bash it works and replaces the value.
But when I have the above, it works partially but replaces the values with blank.

Any tips?

Comment: Side note: you can use `read -p "MySQL Database Name: " MyVar` and get rid of the echo statement.

Comment: Solved the update. I forgot to add '' tags on the strings.
'$blackberg'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/database_name_here/$MyVar/g" config.php
```

to ask shell to interpret the variable, you need to use double quotes instead.

Comment: No matter what you do, don't click the button to accept it as a solution so people can see your problem is solved.